# How to silently update R for Windows installation

Tags: r

I am aware how to silently install 'R for Windows', but how could I update an existing installation silently to a new version?

Install switches I am currently using:

```
\\foo\R\R_4.0.5\R-4.0.5-win.exe  /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NORESTART /ALLUSERS /LANGUAGE=en /COMPONENTS="main, x64, translations" /DIR="C:\Program Files\R"
```

For me, it seems like there is no supported update/upgrade switch. Just installing a new version over an existing one results in just having 2 versions listed in `appwiz.cpl`.

Forcing the same install dir is not helping either, as you still end up with 2 installations, just in the same folder.

Any hint is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
I am trying to keep the installations on several machines aligned - therefor it would be helpful to update all machine installations periodically to the latest version and ensure the software inventory solution is not reporting N versions on a single machine.

Comment: R is designed so that you can have multiple versions installed simultaneously. What is your REAL question?

Comment: The question is as stated above: is there an option to update an existing installation without ending up with multiple versions installed?

Comment: Delete the old version

Answer (score 1):

R is designed so that you can have multiple versions installed simultaneously. This is why each version installs into a different directory.

The canonical way to handle this is to check a registry key for the latest installed version, but if you want to avoid messing with the registry, you can try this:

1. Install into a custom directory
2. When it comes to upgrading, move that directory to a temporary location
3. Install the newer version into the original location
4. If it works, delete the temp location
5. If it doesn't, delete the failed install and restore the original

Caveat: untested.

Comment: First of all thanks for the input. This would most likely work - but appwiz.cpl will most likely still list both versions as installed afterwards.